# What is a proper way for handling actions (events) of the UITableView cell subviews?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swift, model-view-controller

I have a `UITableView` with custom cells. Each cell has a rather complex layout and a lot of child views all of which has event actions: `UIImageView` with gesture recogniser, several `UIButtons` with some actions, two `UILabel`s with gesture recognizers.
So I'm interested are there some elegant ways to handle target-action for them?
Now I see three ways:

1. Handle actions with blocks (`BlocksKit` to the rescue) right in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`
2. Create custom class `CellEventHandler`, pass to it all needed dependencies (controller's `navigation controller`, data array, etc.) and place all the cell's views action selectors there.
3. Write all the selectors in the TableViewController (default way)

But I'm not satisfied with all this ways. Can someone describe some elegant way which will help to make controller thin, and also will be easy maintainble. I'm sure there should exist some pattern for this workflow.

Comment: Sorry for removing your p.s. Your question seems legit and since there is only one vote for closing it present there is no need for "an attitude".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use delegation. When constructing a cell, set it's delegate attribute to some instance that conforms your delegation protocol. When actions are triggered, simply delegate the behavior to the delegate.

That way, you end up with well defined delegation protocol and functionality encapsulated in that class. It is up to you whether the delegate will be e.g. TableViewController or a custom class.

Comment: Up-vote for elegance of solution but I think in most cases it will end up making the UITableViewController confirm to even more protocols than it already does making them even lengthier.

Comment: You don't have to use the UITableViewController, just initialize your delegate in it and pass it to the table cells.

Comment: If I understood you correctly i should have all the action handlers in the delegate custom class, like `didUserImageClick:` and etc. ? And when i will setup cell I have to init its delegate and then write: `[userImage addTarget:delegate action:@selector( didUserImageClick:)]`. Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: If you'd done it that way, the delegate isn't be a real "delegate", but rather a method container. What I would do is defining a very simple placeholder methods and keeping the reference to delegate in your UITableViewCell. You don't initialize the delegate in the cell itself, but in UITableView class and only pass the reference to it. Then, the placeholders (I assume IBActions if you're using these, or selectors otherwise) only need to call something like (in Swift) self.delegate.didUserImageClick(...).

Comment: And this delegate methods could be packed into categories: keeps the files from overgrowing.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most efficient way to go about handling a complex cells is to subclass UITableViewCell and have all of the events handled directly in the subclass. You can create IBOutlets and inactions directly in there.

In the `viewForRowAtIndexPath` you can simply call a custom function `initWithObject` that you can declare in the header of your class so even the initial setup of the cell is out of the viewController greatly simplifying the setup.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Will this approach violate `MVC` design principle? (We have event handling in the view class)

Comment: Maybe if you define it very strictly but frankly it's much more elegant than having to figure out what cell triggered the evens. You see a lot of code with tags that I think are a lot more sloppy than neatly arranging the events in the cell that tigers them.

Answer (score 0):

The Views and Actions should be in View of MVC pattern that is Custom cell in your case. You should write one method for gestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer added on your cell) in your custom cell class. Method will identify the type of object which invoke it through introspection i.e. isKindOfClass UIButton/ Label / ImageView. Each object will further identify with its tag like if gestureRecognizer say it is label which invoke this method but which label label1 or label2 now you can compare its tag to detect it.